# Querying for Unique/Distinct IDs and state Date

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

I have been trying to solve this for the past couple of days and couldn't find an answer myself, so I'm hoping that someone can either point me to the answer or help me himself.

The problem is, lets say that I have 2 different domains - one called vehicle and another called vehicle_history. Now, every time that someone changes a specific vehicle, a new object/new entry is made into the history table. And what I want to do, is make a query that gets every single vehicles state by a specific date, without modifying the data that the query returns (sorting lists etc).

Since I know I'm not the best at trying to explain my problems, here's an example:

```
id     vehicle_id  date_created  state  
1      1           12.08.2015    291
2      2           12.08.2015    212
3      1           14.08.2015    302
4      1           18.08.2015    201
```

It doesn't matter what data there is in the 4th column, we just know that we can't query based on that.

So, currently if I made a query with no date, it should return just two entries: 2 and 4. If I made a query with date 16.08.2015, it should return: 2 and 3.

One of the ways that I have found to work, is querying the database and making projections

```
                projections {
                    max "dateCreated"
                    groupProperty "vehicle.id"
                    groupProperty "vehicle"
                }
```

[and I can't just use projections to get the data, because one of the values that I need to get with the query is an integer]

to get the max 'dateCreated' and 'vehicle_id' to use (because I need the vehicle_history_id not the vehicle_id)

```
def query = VehicleHistory.where {
    vehicle.id = vId
    dateCreated = dtCreated
}
```

But that has proven to be too slow, since there can be over 20 thousand entries in the table.

I haven't added the rest of the filters because they seem irrelevant to the current problem.

Comment: `[and I can't just use projections to get the data, because one of the values that I need to get with the query is an integer]` I didn't get that

Comment: If I try to add a GroupProperty or property it tells me that:

ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function ,

and if I try to add groupProperty('amount') or groupProperty('id') then it just returns all the different ones

Answer (score 0):

```
VehicleHistory.withCriteria{   
  projections {
    max 'dateCreated'
    max 'vehicle.id'
    groupProperty 'vehicle.id'
    property 'id'
    property 'state'
    property 'amount'
  }
}
```

should do

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "this_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function